# Removing selectedItem from ObservableCollection using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, listboxitem

I want to remove an item from an ObservableCollection while adhering to MVVM. I understand the task, I think I understand the logic pretty well and have implemented it, but the item is never removed in the view.

I have traced the application with breakpoints and the value of selectedProject is being read correctly. I also added variables to check the Collection size before and after the remove statement, which were the same value so it therefore does not remove the item. My question is why? What have I missed? What rules have I not adhered to? Pretty new to .NET.

**I am using a WCF Service, to return an ObservableCollection of Projects from my CodeFirst DB and this is called as soon as a user opens the Projects view.

**View**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject}" SelectedIndex="{Binding ProjectIndex}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="60,195,218.8,212.4">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" Content="Up" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="563,195,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="35" Width="75"/>
```

**ViewModel**

```
private ObservableCollection<Project> _projectList;
public ObservableCollection<Project> ProjectList
    {
        get 
        {
            var q = client.ReturnProjects().ToList();
            _projectList = new ObservableCollection<Project>(q.ToList());
            return _projectList;
        }
        set
        {
            _projectList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProjectList");
        }

public int SelectedProject
    {
        get { return _selectedProject; }
        set
        {
            _selectedProject = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProject");
        }
    }
```

The method executed by the command is as follows, the command is being hit and the method called.

```
public void DeleteProject()
        {

            if (SelectedProject != null)
            {
                ProjectList.Remove(SelectedProject);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a two-way-binding for the SelectedItem property.

View

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectList}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"
            Content="Delete"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

ViewModel, Model and ICommand Implementation

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        var q = new[] { new Project() { Name = "A" }, new Project() { Name = "B" }, new Project() { Name = "C" } };
        ProjectList = new ObservableCollection<Project>(q);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Project> _projectList;

    public ObservableCollection<Project> ProjectList
    {
        get
        {
            return _projectList;
        }
        set
        {
            _projectList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProjectList");
        }
    }

    Project _selectedProject;
    public Project SelectedProject
    {
        get { return _selectedProject; }
        set
        {
            _selectedProject = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProject");
        }
    }

    public ICommand DeleteCommand => new SimpleCommand(DeleteProject);

    private void DeleteProject()
    {

        if (SelectedProject != null)
        {
            ProjectList.Remove(SelectedProject);
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Project
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SimpleCommand : ICommand
{
    Action _execute;
    public SimpleCommand(Action execute)
    {
        this._execute = execute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the `Mode=TwoWay` , this didn't resolve the issue. I also don't understand why it should have as SelectedItem is only allowing me to retrieve the item I am looking to remove.

Comment: The user changes the selection in the UI (View). With Two-Way-Binding, the ViewModels property SelectedItem gets updated. 
I will edit my answer and post a working solution.

Comment: That makes sense Thomas, thanks. What I don't understand is that when I trace with breakpoints, I can see that the correct selectedItem has been passed into the ViewModel, however the call to remove does not change the list on the view in anyway.

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know, if you still have a question.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. This however is the same as my solution.  I have my commands in helper class.

Comment: I'm away from my machine but I will be sure to when I get in. Thanks again Thomas. :)

Comment: Thomas, thanks for all your help with this. It is working perfectly. The most noticeable difference was that I had not initialized my ProjectList in the ViewModel constructor. Regardless, thank you very much for your time with this. Makes the fear of posting questions worth it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think OnPropertyChanged("ProjectList") needs to be called after deleting the item to raise the notification for updating the view .

Comment: Unfortunately not the fix.

Answer (score 0):

The ObservableCollection has to interact with the model layer.
Maybe you need this:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bethmassi/2009/05/08/using-the-wpf-observablecollection-with-ef-entities/